# web configuration changing effects on hosted application

Tags: iis

Is it mandatory to refresh the **application pool** and website hosted on IIS 7.5 when are changes made to the web application's web configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

It does it automatically, so no it's not mandatory to do it a second time, it just happens. :)